# 21:9 2560x1080 on Mini late 2012

Tags: display, mac-mini, graphics, hdmi, gpu

I just bought an LG 21:9 monitor, with a native resolution of 2560x1080p at 60 Hz.

Now, my mac mini late 2012 (HD4000) allow me to select resolutions up to 1920x1080p and no more. 
The monitor is connected via HDMI, but the HDMI on the mini should be able to output up to 2560x1440p@60Hz...

Any advice?

Comment: Does your monitor support Display Port?

Comment: If your monitor has Displayport (which I think all ultrawide LGs do) you can use that instead of buying the very expensive DualLink-DVI adapter.

Comment: Problem is the DP input is already used by a workstation that has DP outputs only. I suppose I'll have to put the mac on DP and buy some adaptor for the ws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MacTracker.app:

- Display Connection    1 - HDMI port or Thunderbolt digital video output
- Display Support   Supports an HDMI-compatible device while using one Thunderbolt display or support for two Thunderbolt displays
- Display Modes Dual display extended, video mirroring, and AirPlay Mirroring
- External Resolution   Up to 2560 by 1600 (Thunderbolt) or **1920 by 1200 (HDMI)**

Concluding: You need a Thunderbolt display adapter for your new display